# How can I uninstall IBM True Key that came bundled with Adobe Reader?

Tags: uninstall, adobe-reader, unwanted-application

I am using windows 7. It doesn't appear in the list of programs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files\Intel Security\True Key and run the uninstall.exe file.